# need to use orderby function with groupby function

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT com_jobcard.job_card_num, sum( worked_qty ),employee.emp_name
FROM timer_completed
INNER JOIN process ON process.id = timer_completed.process_id
INNER JOIN com_jobcard ON com_jobcard.id = timer_completed.job_card_id
INNER JOIN employee ON employee.id = timer_completed.employee_id
AND process.id = '611'
AND timer_completed.group_id = '60'
AND timer_completed.report_date = DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -1 DAY)
GROUP BY com_jobcard.job_card_num
UNION 
SELECT job_card_num , die_qty,id FROM com_jobcard
```

in this query I've used SUM() and group by option but my ultimate result is I've to sort the result with com_jobcard.job_card_num in DESC order could any one suggest me

Comment: i have done some changes in your query, check my answer.

Comment: You will have duplicate values for the first column in your result. Is that really what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Try out this:

```
select * from(    
  SELECT com_jobcard.job_card_num, sum( worked_qty ),employee.emp_name
  FROM timer_completed
  INNER JOIN process ON process.id = timer_completed.process_id
  INNER JOIN com_jobcard ON com_jobcard.id = timer_completed.job_card_id
  INNER JOIN employee ON employee.id = timer_completed.employee_id
  AND process.id = '611'
  AND timer_completed.group_id = '60'
  AND timer_completed.report_date = DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -1 DAY)
  GROUP BY com_jobcard.job_card_num
  UNION 
  SELECT job_card_num , die_qty,id FROM com_jobcard
 ) as t1 order by t1.job_card desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add at the end of your query:

```
ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

This means: sort by the first column descending.